# Unwanted number calculation result

Tags: java, integer

Ok so I'm writing a program that gives a user a set of equations depending on how many they wish to do. After it runs and the user answers all the questions a report is generated. My code for the report is simple:

```
public void report(){
    percent = (totalCorrect / numberOfQuestions) * 100;
    totalTime = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
    System.out.println("Report:");
    System.out.println("Questions Answered: " + numberOfQuestions);
    System.out.println("Total Correct: " + totalCorrect);
    System.out.println("Total Incorrect: " + totalIncorrect);
    System.out.println("Percent: " + percent + "%");
    System.out.println("Time taken: " + totalTime + " seconds");
}
```

However the result is:

```
Report:
Questions Answered: 2
Total Correct: 1
Total Incorrect: 1
Percent: 0.0%
Time taken: 2 seconds
```

This is correct, I purposely answered one correct and one incorrect. My question is the percentage is always 0.0% unless I get them all right in which case it is 100%. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. It's recording the correct number of answers that are correct (based on the "Total Correct: " output) and the number of questions. And obviously my equation for percentage is correct. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Well that's the same old school issue of Integer Division - `5 / 100 == 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have performed integer division, if `totalCorrect` and `numberOfQuestions` are `int` in your program.  In integer division in Java, the result must also be an `int` so the result is truncated.

Cast one of the variables to `double` before performing the division, so Java will perform floating-point division first.

```
percent = ((double) totalCorrect / numberOfQuestions) * 100;
```

Comment: I had a feeling it was something very basic that slipped my mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you're probably doing integer division.

One or both of your variables `totalCorrect` and `numberOfQuestions` needs to be a double, at least at the time of calculation.

Try this:

```
percent = ((double)totalCorrect / numberOfQuestions) * 100;
```

Maulzey gives another good alternative that doesn't cast from int to double.